# Cross-Origin Request Blocked after installing the CORS gem: when trying to use PUSHER for pop up notification in a blog application

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.1, pusher

config/application.rb file

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'


Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)



module Blog
  class Application < Rails::Application

    config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors", :debug => true, :logger => (-> { Rails.logger }) do
    allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '/cors',
    :headers => :any,
    :methods => [:post],
    :credentials => true,
    :max_age => 0
    resource '*',
    :headers => :any,
    :methods => [:get, :post, :delete, :put, :options, :head],
    :max_age => 0
    end
    end
  end
end
```

pusher_controller.rb
pusher api is used for the pop up notofocation as said in takeofflabs.com

```
class PusherController < ApplicationController
def auth


    if current_user && params[:channel_name]=="private-user-current-#{current_user_id}"
        response = Pusher[params[:channel_name]].authenticate(params[:socket_id])
        render :json => response
    else
        render "not_authorized" , :status =>'403'
    end

end

def show
    Pusher.app_id = PUSHER_APP_ID
Pusher.key = PUSHER_KEY
Pusher.secret = PUSHER_SECRET
        x= render_to_string(:partial => "/views/notifications/notification")
        Pusher["private-user-#{@notification.user_id}"].trigger('new-notification',x)
    end 
end
```

environment.rb file
    require File.expand_path('../application', **FILE**)

```
PUSHER_APP_ID = "101053"
PUSHER_KEY = "89979ad24549eabc3764"
PUSHER_SECRET = "f4c1a6ca70d523e9e72e"
```

application.html.erb

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Blog</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://js.pusherapp.com/2.2/pusher.min.js" %>


<script>

  var pusher = new Pusher("#{PUSHER_KEY}");
  var userChannel = pusher.subscribe("private-user-#{current_user.id}");
userChannel.bind('new-notification', function(message) {
   $(".notifications_area").html(message);
 });

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <%if current_user %>
Logged in as: <%= current_user.email if current_user %>
<%else%>
PLEASE LOG IN TO SEE THE ARTICLES
<%end%>
<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
    Rails.application.initialize!
```

Answer (score 0):

Although your question doesn't directly say this I'm assuming that the CORS error occurs when the [private channel](http://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_private_channels) subscription [authentication](http://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users#implementing_private_endpoints) is taking place.

I'm not too familiar with [Rack CORS](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) however the way these things usually work is that they require an authentication token to be passed with any request to the server. The way to do this in with the Pusher JavaScript library is to pass in an `auth` option when you construct the `Pusher` instance:

```
var options = {
  auth: {
    headers: {
      'x-domain-token': YOUR_CORS_TOKEN
    }
  }
};
var pusher = new Pusher( YOUR_APP_KEY, options );
```

You will need to check:

- Where Rack CORS expects the token to be. It may be in a header or as a `POST` or `GET` parameter. You can also set these via `options`
- What the name of the parameter is. Above I've guessed at `x-domain-token`

For information on `options` see the Pusher docs on the [options.auth parameter](http://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_connect#auth-smallobjectsmall).

There is also a [Pusher CSRF RoR FAQ](https://support.pusher.com/hc/en-us/articles/202085526-Ruby-on-Rails-Pusher-authenticate-logging-out-user-CSRF-) which may provide additional insight.